# How to replace bottom plate on non-load bearing wall

Tags: bathroom, repair, walls

I recently purchased a house and am trying to DIY as much as I can so that I can learn how to do things correctly.

I'm looking to replace the bottom plate in my bathroom and just want to make sure I've got the right idea.

This interior wall is not load-bearing from what I can tell. I climbed in the attic and there is no direct load holding up the roof and the joist do not split and sit on top of this wall.

The plate itself looks ok but when I hit it with a hammer, it does chip away fairly easily. I assume it's better to replace while the wall is open instead of trying to replace it later.

My plan was to saw the nails with a multi-tool, slide the plate out, and insert the new plate. Seems simple enough but since I'm still learning, I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

[image: bathroom bottom wall plate]

[image: bathroom bottom wall plate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much it. You'll know when you start cutting the stud nails whether there's significant pressure on the plate (the saw will move instead of the blade, and you along with it--it's a fun ride with a reciprocating saw :) ). If there is, you might use a jack to (gently) life the ceiling adjacent. Pad it well and don't punch through your drywall. Move it barely enough to relieve the pressure.

Comment: Thanks! There was basically no load on the wall. It just floated as I replaced the framing. https://imgur.com/OHdTDYr